# Join table in Snowflake using between in where clause

Tags: mysql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have Week table -

```
Week,   Friday_dates,   Start_date, End_date
1,      2021-07-16,     2021-07-12, 2021-07-18
2,      2021-07-23,     2021-07-19, 2021-07-25
```

and so on..

I have another table with list of details by date

```
Date,        To_do_list
20220-01-02, Text 
20220-01-03, Call
20220-01-03, Text
20220-01-04, Call
20220-01-05, Call
```

I want count no of to_do_list where it says Call and want join this table with date table for specific dates falling under start_date and end_date.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Join the tables, with `date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date` as the joining condition. Use `to_do_list = 'Call'` in the `WHERE` condition. And use `COUNT(*)` to get the count.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do but got stuck -- 


select * from Weeks a
 left join (select Date, count(*) from Activity
           where To_do_list like '%Call%'
          group by DATE) b 
on a.FRIDAY = where b.DATE in between STARTDATE and ENDDATE

I am stuck on where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So  given your data (I am using a CTE so I don't have to create the tables)

```
WITH Weeks(Week, Friday_dates, Start_date, End_date) as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    (1, '2021-07-16'::date, '2021-07-12'::date, '2021-07-18'::date),
    (2, '2021-07-23'::date, '2021-07-19'::date, '2021-07-25'::date)
), Activity(Date, To_do_list) as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    ('20220-01-02'::date, 'Text'),
    ('20220-01-03'::date, 'Call'),
    ('20220-01-03'::date, 'Text'),
    ('20220-01-04'::date, 'Call'),
    ('20220-01-05'::date, 'Call')
)
```

To join the `activity` to the `weeks` and limit the count to just the call's, which will be counted per week, you would:

```
SELECT w.Friday_dates
    ,count(*) as call_count
FROM Activity AS a
JOIN Weeks AS w
    on a.DATE between w.Start_date and w.End_date
WHERE a.To_do_list = 'Call'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

which gives no results as none of your weeks overlap the activity time ranges.

So if we change the data to be overlapping:

```
WITH Weeks(Week, Friday_dates, Start_date, End_date) as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    (1, '2021-07-16'::date, '2021-07-12'::date, '2021-07-18'::date),
    (2, '2021-07-23'::date, '2021-07-19'::date, '2021-07-25'::date)
), Activity(Date, To_do_list) as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    ('2021-07-18'::date, 'Text'),
    ('2021-07-18'::date, 'Call'),
    ('2021-07-18'::date, 'Text'),
    ('2021-07-19'::date, 'Call'),
    ('2021-07-20'::date, 'Call')
)
```

we now get:

| FRIDAY_DATES | CALL_COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-07-16 | 1 |
| 2021-07-23 | 2 |

But if we take you SQL from the comment and make it valid:

```
select * from Weeks a 
left join (
    select Date, 
        count(*) from Activity 
    where To_do_list like '%Call%' 
    group by DATE
) b 
    on b.DATE between a.Start_date and a.End_date 
ORDER BY 1;
```

we get..

| WEEK | FRIDAY_DATES | START_DATE | END_DATE | DATE | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-07-16 | 2021-07-12 | 2021-07-18 | 2021-07-18 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-07-23 | 2021-07-19 | 2021-07-25 | 2021-07-19 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-07-23 | 2021-07-19 | 2021-07-25 | 2021-07-20 | 1 |